# Check Visual Studio Shell Installation from Batch

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-shell

How can we check if and which version of Visual Studio Shell is installed, from a batch script?

I understand we can check the existence of file/folder say under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

But I am looking for a more elegant and generic solution.

Any help?

***Update to accepted answer:***

Your answer is elegant and does the task. Since I was specifically checking for certain versions, I am using (after checking the link you provided):

```
@echo off
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE.10.0" >> nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( echo VS 2010 not installed ) else ( echo VS 2010 installed. )
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE.11.0" >> nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( echo VS 2012 not installed ) else ( echo VS 2012 installed. )
```

Comment: What do you want to know? The version number or the version name? i.e 10 or express/pro etc.

Comment: either of them or both will do.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just for future reference, put any updates into your question with a clear title (see my edit) rather than edit the solution, so it makes more sense. Nice to see you got `reg query` working though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio*") do (
for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%x in ("%%a") do echo %%x
)
pause >nul
```

If you need more details there are [plenty of reg keys](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx) you can query to get more info but that would be much harder to extract the data you wanted from the keys and values.

***Note:*** If you are running on x64 then you may need to add a check for `%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)` depending on where VS is installed.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for notifying me on the edit, I have added the OP's response into their question so it is there for future readers.